# Effective Way To Get Recapitulation From A Tabel

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Anybody know what's the effective way (at least a concept) to get a recapitulation from table A without writing too much code, so I can get the result as table recapitulation. Initially, The first think I do grouping the table A, but I'm just stuck how to calculate the average value of the same subject from the same ID1. Any idea?

[image]

The help will be very highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to eliminate column `ID2` and group table by columns `ID1`,`Subject`?

Comment: what is the formula for recapitalization?

Comment: Is it the sum of the unique values of ID1 and Subject divided by the the number of unique values of id/subject for a given id?

Comment: Igor: I do.
Orangepill: Yes, it's just average. ex: 002 for subject A would be (6+3)/2 = 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the exact formula but from the sample data I am going to make some assumptions

```
 SELECT `id1`, `subject`,`year` SUM(`value`)/COUNT(DISTINCT `id2`) 
 FROM tabel_score 
 GROUP BY `id1`, `subject`, `year`;
```

Again this is a guess.

**UPDATE**

For integration into a SQL Server database had to multiply the divisor by 1.0 for force it to a float and for keep it from doing integer division so the updated query is:

```
 SELECT `id1`, `subject`,`year` SUM(`value`)/(COUNT(DISTINCT `id2`) * 1.0)
 FROM tabel_score 
 GROUP BY `id1`, `subject`, `year`;
```

Comment: Did it run out of the box on sql server or did you have to tweak it?

Comment: so far no. but wait, SUM(`value`)/COUNT(DISTINCT `id2`) give me integer value, how to change it to decimal value? convert(decimal(18,2), SUM(`value`)/COUNT(DISTINCT `id2`) ) doesn't work.

Comment: the decimal portion is probably already gone by the time you call that... try `SUM(value)/(COUNT(DISTINCT id2) * 1.0)` to force the divisor to a decimal.

Comment: Great! Thank again Orangepill..
It solved my problem..
heheheh